# Is there a way to convert rows to columns depending on values Using R

Tags: r

I have data which is loaded into a dataframe as

```
unitid  date_time       sensor  sample
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  1       0
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  3       0
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  6       22
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  7       35
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:35  1       0
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:35  3       0
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:35  6       22
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:35  7       35
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:36  1       0
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:36  3       0
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:36  6       37
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:36  7       56
```

I have tried using mutate() function to keep data in separate column as

```
df<- group_by(data1, unitid) %>% 
arrange(datee_time) %>% 
mutate(sensor1 = lag(sensor,1), sensor3 = lag(sensor,3),sensor6 = lag(sensor,6),sensor7 = lag(sensor,7))%>% 
group_by(unitid, sample_time_conv)
```

am getting out put as

```
unitid  date_time       sensor  sample  sensor1 sensor3 sensor7 sensor9
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  1       0       7       3       6       3
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  3       0       1       6       7       6
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  6       22      3       7       1       7
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  7       35      6       1       3       1
```

and so on. Which is incorrect.

Expected output should be

```
unitid  date_time       sensor1 sensor3 sensor6 sensor7
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:34  0       0       22      35
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:35  0       0       22      35
b0a25   10/1/2015 5:36  0       0       37      56
```

Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Have a look at `?reshape`.

Comment: Since you are apparently a disciple of the Church of Hadley, you should look into the reshape2 or tidyr package.

Comment: so what exactly is your columns ? I mean do you want to just transpose ? or something else ?

Comment: @nicola reshape is consuming lot of time to execute

Comment: @nicola, initially because of in proper values it took lot of time. But reshape gave me expected output. Answer is shared below

Answer (score 0):

This can be done by the spread function in tidyr

```
df %>% mutate(sensor=paste("sensor",sensor)) %>% spread(sensor,sample)
```

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using reshape() as below solution

```
samplereshape<-reshape(data1,v.names="sample",idvar="date_time",timevar="sensor",direction="wide")
```

rename the column by using colnames.